# Java: creating an array of objects using a data file

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have an issue with an code for class where I am supposed to read data from a file "data.txt" then create an array of People objects using the data from the file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 public class PersonDemo
 {
   public PersonDemo() throws FileNotFoundException
   {
    Person[] people = new Person[10]; // creating Person object array
    int flag; // to identify whether person, student or instructor
    try{
        File f = new File("data.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(f);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            while (in.hasNext())
            {
                final String[] arr = in.next().split(" ");
```

// secondary array to hold elements read in from file NOT WORKING

```
                flag =  Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
                if (flag == 1)
                {
                    people[i] = new Person(arr[1], Integer.parseInt(arr[2])); // creates Person
```

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 --- this exception occurs during the above line of code and I am unsure as to why, I am not even sure if my code is correct.. just that it compiles.

```
                } else if (flag == 2)
                {
                    people[i] = new Student(arr[1], Integer.parseInt(arr[2]), arr[3], arr[4]); // creates Student

                } else if (flag == 3)
                {
                    people[i] = new Instructor(arr[1], Integer.parseInt(arr[2]), Double.parseDouble(arr[3])); // creates Instructor
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("no file found"); // error catch
    }

    for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
    {
        people[z].toString(); //print out the people
    }
}
```

}

anyone have any insight as to how I can fix the exception and get the code to work?

The data file is in style of;

identifier -- name -- age -- studentID/salary -- major

1   Larry   50

2   Joe 20  12345   Computer_Science

3   Sally   40  40000

2   Smith   21  23231   Compuer_Security

1   Mary    32

3   Michael 49  80000

2   Amy     23  34343   Information_Tech

1   John    5

3   Darren  54  99995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs because Scanner `next()` is used instead of `nextLine()`.  You will want to read the entire line with `nextLine()`, since you are parsing it with a String `split()`.

The people array is not being populated correctly because the while loop is inside of the for loop.  The while loop will cause the entire data file to be scanned during one iteration of the for loop.  This means `i` will be zero and only `people[0]` will be populated.  You can fix this by removing the for loop and just tracking the index in a variable:

```
        int i = 0;
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            final String[] arr = in.nextLine().split(" ");
            // do work
            i++;
        }
```

This should fix your exception and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

change the while to if . such as 'while (in.hasNext())' to if(in.hasNextLine())  .   because the method hasNext() is scaned by word while the hasNextLine() is scaned by line.

```
File f = new File("data.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(f);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (in.hasNextLine()) {
                final String[] arr = in.nextLine().split(" ");
                flag = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
                if (flag == 1) {
                    people[i] = new Person(arr[1], Integer.parseInt(arr[2])); // creates
                                                                                // Person
                } else if (flag == 2) {
                    people[i] = new Student(arr[1],
                    Integer.parseInt(arr[2]), arr[3], arr[4]); // creates
                    Student

                } else if (flag == 3) {
                    people[i] = new Instructor(arr[1],
                    Integer.parseInt(arr[2]),
                    Double.parseDouble(arr[3])); // creates Instructor
                }
            }
```

but use the Person[] people = new Person[10];  is not recommand here.you can use ArrayList to replace.
just like this:

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
    int flag; // to identify whether person, student or instructor
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "data.txt"));
        String line;
        Person person;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            final String[] arr = line.split(" ");
            flag = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
            if (flag == 1) {
                person = new Person(arr[1], Integer.parseInt(arr[2])); // creates
                people.add(person);

            } else if (flag == 2) {
                person = new Student(arr[1], Integer.parseInt(arr[2]),
                        arr[3], arr[4]); // creates
                people.add(person);

            } else if (flag == 3) {
                person = new Instructor(arr[1], Integer.parseInt(arr[2]),
                        Double.parseDouble(arr[3])); // creates Instructor
                people.add(person);
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("no file found"); // error catch
    }

    for (Person p : people) {
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }
```